# `npm run` command doesn't obey the file seek pattern

Tags: node.js, npm, package.json

Ok, I never faced this problem before. It's very strange. I've a package.json scripts as folowed:

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --coverage",
    "lint": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./src/**/*.{js,md} --fix",
    "format": "node_modules/prettier-standard/src/cli.js ./src/**/*.{js,md} --fix",
    "start": "sls offline"
  }
}
```

If I type `npm run lint` for example, the pattern for seek files seems doesn't work (going through only the first subfolder). But if I exec the command at the terminal it works fine.

The question: why this works fine
`~ node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ./src/**/*.{js,md} --fix` 
and this won't
`npm run lint`?

Comment: Can you really just name a .js file like that as the first argument in the script value without having `node` in there?  Does this require some kind of file association to be set up with .js files to work?  I was expecting `"node node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js ..."`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem just wrapping the **seek pattern** into single quotes.

```
{
  "scripts": {
    "test": "node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --coverage",
    "lint": "node_modules/eslint/bin/eslint.js './src/**/*.{js,md}' --fix",
    "format": "node_modules/prettier-standard/src/cli.js './src/**/*.{js,md}' --fix",
    "start": "sls offline"
  }
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using a full path to the modules? You only need to install the modules and npm will figure out where the scripts are.

```
npm i -D eslint jest prettier
```

If the pattern for files still does not work, try to surround it by `'...'`, there used to be known issues about that

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "jest --coverage",
    "lint": "eslint './src/**/*.{js,md}' --fix",
    "format": "prettier './src/**/*.{js,md}' --fix",
    "start": "sls offline"
}
```

Comment: If dependency has been globally installed, it works correctly.. but, doesn't looks right. I Believe it's a module's issue because jest works fine!